# get public ip address from web api 2

Tags: asp.net, api, rest

going to create rest api web API service for that i want to track the user country and show some result according to country can any one assist how to track the public ip address

Answer (score 0):

That information generally isn't available. The best you'll probably be able to do is either the [Referer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.36) header or the [Accept-Language](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.4) header.